# Read json value from the http response trigger by invoke-webrequest

Tags: powershell

I am trying to fetch a particular value from the JSON response of an invoke-web request. But the value is not capturing
Tried using the following script, where the `$body` contains the response.

```
$url = "http://localhost:9096/getMachineStatus"
$HTTP_Request = [System.Net.WebRequest]::Create($url)
$HTTP_Response = $HTTP_Request.GetResponse()
$HTTP_Status = [int]$HTTP_Response.StatusCode
$body = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $url
```

The response of the above script:

```
 {
      "Name": "LocalTestMachine",
      "Profile": "QA",
      "Stacks": [
        {
          "Region": "Mumbai-1",
          "State": "Stopped",
          "StackName": "QA",
          "StackCreationStatus": "CREATE_Success",
          "Instances": [
            {
              "MachineName": "LocalMachine",
              "IpAddress": "10.10.10.164",
              "State": "stopped",
              "InstanceId": "i-0777e90151b22da44",
              "ImageId": "ami-0322ff2d8d099g56c",
              "CustomImageName": "ubuntu-trusty-16.04",
              "InstanceType": "m4.large",
              "LaunchTime": "2019-09-04T02:42:36-04:00",
              "AvailabilityZone": "Mumbai-1",
              "Tags": [
                {
                  "Key": "ProductLine",
                  "Value": "Cloud"
                }]
            }]
        }]
    }
```

I just want to retrieve the value associated with the object `State` which is `Stopped`.

I tried with
  `$currentVMState = $body | where {$_.State}`
It is not working

Comment: Which value do you want to retrieve?

Comment: @arco444 the first `State` value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to convert the response to json:

```
$json = $body | ConvertFrom-Json
```

Then iterate the `$json` object to get the state value:

```
$json.stacks.instances | ForEach-Object { $_.State }
```

Comment: I tried it, I guess the response is in JSON when I tried above and print, it is giving me 
`@{Name=LocalTestMachine; AwsProfile=QA; Stacks=System.Object[];}`
and the final value of `$json.stacks.instances | ForEach-Object { $_.State }` is an empty string.

Comment: Is the body you posted in the question exactly the same as what is returned by the web request? This would suggest you have another element higher up in the json doc.

Comment: Yeah, the exact body is posted, `@{Name=LocalTestMachine; Profile=QA; Stacks=System.Object[];LastUpdated=;LastUpdatedLocally=;SubmitInProgress=;SubmitInProgressAction=;.....State=0}` if you observed the value for `Stacks` is `System.Object[]`. I guess the problem lies here

Comment: I suspect you have not included the full response. You also have `AwsProfile` in your comment here, that is not in the json you pasted in the question. Please update your question to show the full response, do not select only part of it.

Comment: Yeah got it, found the answer. That part was missed. Now it is working.

Answer (score 2):

To get the value of the **first** `State` item in the `Stacks` array, do this:

```
$json = $body | ConvertFrom-Json
$json.Stacks[0].State
```

returns

> Stopped